# Toggle open on page load i am using toggle five times in a page

Tags: jquery

```
 // Available COURSES
 $("div#frontpage-course-list:nth-of-type(1) h2").append("<a id='clps1' class='mycss1 clps-cls'>+</a>");
 $(".frontpage-course-list-all").hide();
 $(".mycss1").show();

   $(".mycss1").toggle(function(){
       $("#clps1").text("-");
       $(".frontpage-course-list-all").slideDown();

   },function(){
       $("#clps1").text("+");
       $(".frontpage-course-list-all").slideUp();
 });
```

Toggle open on page load I am using toggle five times in a page i want to open first toggle open on page please help you can also check on my website 
http://themetesting28.demo.moodlethemes.com/

Comment: you mean the toggle should happen only once on page load instead of 5 times ?

Comment: Now I am using five times with different id all are defaultly hide I want to show first one on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Your1stToggleID").show();
});
```

or use `.toggle()` instead .show();